Barcode Scanner Read Verification
I'm trying to use a barcode pistol to check some serial numbers. The problem is that the tag has multiple codes and sometimes the pistol upload the wrong information into Excel.
All the serial numbers start with an "S". So my idea is when Excel register the serial number it verifies if it starts with as "S". If it starts with "S", no sound is played, and it goes to the next cell, else plays a sound that indicates that the code is not correct.
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Cell As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo ExitSub

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("H")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each Cell In Target
     If Left(Cell.Value, 1) <> "S" Then
        Call PlayCustomSound
     End If
   
Next Cell
End If

ExitSub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

I almost have it working, but the problem I have is that it verifies the next cell and not the code that was placed on the previous cell.
If with my mouse I just click on one that has an "S", no sound is played, if it doesn't have an "S" it's playing the sound.
If possible, I would like to add that when it doesn't have an "S", instead of going to the next cell it keeps on the same cell until I upload a code starting with an "S".

Handle Worksheet_Change instead of Worksheet_SelectionChange?

A Worksheet Change: Check If String Begins With Substring (Barcode Scanner)

You should use the Worksheet Change event instead as suggested by GSerg in the your comments.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "H2"
    Const BEGINS_WITH_STRING As String = "S"
    
    ' Assuming the scanner populates one cell at a time.
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the target range ('H2:H1048576').
    Dim trg As Range:
    With Me.Range(FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        Set trg = .Resize(Me.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Check if the cell is not in the target range.
    If Intersect(trg, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Check if the entered code begins with 'BEGINS_WITH_STRING'.
    ' This comparison ('InStr') is case-sensitive i.e. "S" <> "s".
    Dim TargetString As String: TargetString = CStr(Target.Value)
    If InStr(TargetString, BEGINS_WITH_STRING) = 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    PlayCustomSound ' ?
    'Target.Select
    
    ' It is necessary to disable events only when modifying ('changing')
    ' cells in the same worksheet!
    
'    ' Clear the wrong code.
'    Application.EnableEvents = False
'        Target.ClearContents
'    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub 

